# Process zip files

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, file, compression

I have zip bundle, for example, abcd.zip, contains more zips like 1.zip, 2.zip etc. Inside of each child zip there is a .jpg file like 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. There are so many other files but I need only .jpeg.

I need to extract the .jpeg's and and create a zip it again with same parent name like 1.zip.

This works fine, but just wanted to know if I can make it faster. There will be approx 30,000 zip I need to process.

```
def fjpeg(file):
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    jp = base[:-4]+".jpg"
    return jp    

def process(bundle):
    z1 = zp.ZipFile(bundle, 'r')
    for z1file in z1.namelist():
        if z1file[-4:] == '.zip':
            z2 = zp.ZipFile(z1.extract(z1file, "tmp"), 'r')
            z3 = os.path.basename(z2.extract(fjpeg(z1file)))
            process_path = "processed" + os.path.sep + os.path.basename(z1file)
            with zp.ZipFile(process_path, 'w', mode) as final:
                final.write(z3)
            z2.close()    
            os.unlink(os.path.join("tmp", z1file))
            os.unlink(z3)
        else:
            continue
    z1.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to create temporary files on disk, as [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) can work in-memory.

- Use a [`cStringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) instance to hold a zip file in memory.
- Use `ZipFile.read` to read a jpeg file into a `str` variable.
- Use `ZipFile.writestr` to write the jpeg back.

This Stack Overflow question may be useful to you: [Unzip nested zip files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11930515/222914). As mentioned, decompressing zip files requires random access to the archive. If the "bundle" zip stores its contents uncompressed (which is an option), in theory it should be possible to have random access into the files.

Comment: Single zip file is as big as 2 gigs

Comment: @DevC If you mean the "bundle" file, I'm not suggesting to pull that into memory, only the temporary files.

Comment: Bundle is approx 10G, and has other zip approx 1-2 gig each... Which at last has jpg approx 25 mb... I can read jpg in memory though

Answer (score 2):

If @JanneKarila's suggestion to unzip in memory instead of disk didn't seem to work for you, I don't know how to make it faster. 
But in any case, there's some room for improvement.

Instead of this:

> ```
> z1 = zp.ZipFile(bundle, 'r')
> # ...
> z1.close()
> ```

It would be better to use `with`, and you can omit `'r'`:

```
with zp.ZipFile(bundle) as z1:
    # ...
```

The same goes for `z2`.

It's confusing that `z1` and `z2` are zip files but `z3` is not.
So you should rename `z3` to something better.